# Get items a .sortable() call will effect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to determine what items will be sorted when using the jQuery.sortable() plugin. For example, I know that there is an object property you can set [items] for what items should be affected by the sort within the selector you call the method against, but if that is not set, how can you determine what it will be. Obviously, if you call it against a 'UL', you can assume that the items will be 'LI' elements. However, what if you have a 'DIV' and the children are 'UL' that the sort would pick up by default, to be effected and sortable, how would you know this, without setting the 'items' property. Any help and or a basic example would be greatly appreciated.

BTW. Hoping I do not have to do a check for direct children of the selector, or even set the items as soon as the first sort occurs, and get the tag type of the item being sorted, as I need this information during initializing it to store in data attributes for later use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sortables can work on any type of DOM element. All that's required is a container (on which you call .sortable()) and then child elements (which can be specified with the 'items' option). The default for items is '> *' which means all immediate children (not descendants) of the container.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ items: "> li" }); // or whatever
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

also check this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/GA4Qs/13/

Comment: I already mention in my question post that I do not want to use the "items" property as the user may not enter that. This is for a plugin that wraps the sort-able plugin, and stores the orders in localStorage for the user. So, if they DO NOT apply a selector to the "items" property, how can I tell what children are the sorted items? What if they set the sortable plugin on a DIV that contains SPAN tags? Do I just take the selector they send to the sortable, and take immediate children, and that will always be what the sortable sorts? The children of the selector in the jquery object?

Comment: did you read this ? The default for items is '> *' which means all immediate children !! so if you leave it by default it will work on any children !!

Comment: Oh crap, my bad. Awesome, that is exactly what I was thinking would make sense, and thankfully, that is how they made it.  Thanks again, and sorry for the confusion.  :)

Comment: You know, I guess I should of just looked at the library code, and checked out what they default to in the jQueryUI method for it....   LOL  Anyways, thanks again.